# Deleting Columns based on header value, withut skipping columns. Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete columns in the data I have based on the header values, using VBA. I am definitely a novice at this, so would appreciate any help. At the moment I have managed to find some code that can do this, except every time I run the macro it deletes some of the columns, but appears to skip some of the columns. I think because when a column is deleted the column then moves to a new location, ie F5 gets deleted so G5 moves to F5 and then manages to escape the query. This is the code

```
Sub DeleteSpecifcColumn()
    Set MR = Range("A1:D1")
    For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "old" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an index variable in your loop based on the column number and loop backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical problem ,If you want to delete rows or columns always begin deleting from the end .

```
Sub DeleteSpecifcColumn()
    For i = 4 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(1, i) = "old" Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Imran - brilliant, so happy with that answer, I've been stuck with this for a while. :)

Comment: you saved my day! "always begin deleting from the end"